# How to debug TypeInitializationException in Awesomium.Mono on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, mono, awesomium

I'm trying to run the basic canonical hello world for Awesomium using:

- Awesomium.Mono (1.7.3)
- Project targets Mono/.Net 4, x86
- console application
- Xamarin studio.

Here's the code:

```
using ( webView = WebCore.CreateWebView( 800, 600 ) )
{
    webView.Source = new Uri( "http://www.google.com" );

    while ( webView.IsLoading )
        WebCore.Update();

    BitmapSurface surface = (BitmapSurface)webview.Surface;
    surface.SaveToPNG( "result.png", true );
}

WebCore.Shutdown();
```

I'm getting a `TypeInitializationException` at WebCore.CreateWebView.

```
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Awesomium.Core.WebCore ---> 
System.Exception: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Awesomium.Core.NativeMethods ---> 
System.Exception: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for AweExceptionHelper ---> 
System.Exception: awesomium
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) 
  at Awesomium.Core.NativeMethods+AweExceptionHelper..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Awesomium.Core.NativeMethods.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Awesomium.Core.NativeMethods..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Awesomium.Core.WebCore..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The tabbed monomac sample that is included in the installation runs without error, so not being very familar with OSX, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I stopped using Mono.